# How to setup Netezza connection using gradle build file?

Tags: java, gradle, netezza, spring-tool-suite

I want to setup a netezza connection using gradle. I have added this:

```
compile group: 'net.sf.squirrel-sql.plugins', name: 'netezza' , version: '3.5.0'
```

And the application properties file looks as follows:

```
# Connection Details for Netezza. Below given contains connection details.
netezza.driverClassName=org.netezza.Driver 
netezza.url=jdbc:netezza://NZ72.XYZ.COM:4487/ABCD
netezza.username=72
netezza.password=726
```

But I get this exception:

> "Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver
>   class 'org.netezza.Driver '"

Comment: where do you want this connection? In your build or within your application?

Comment: I want this in my build file. I am now able to download the file and its showing up in referenced libraries. I am still getting same error. Is the driver name I am using correct ?

Comment: @laletscaria, you need the connection in `build.gradle` script or in a project that is being built with gradle?

Comment: I want it in project.